# duplicate panGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Let's say I have a custom view and I want to add gesture recognizer to it.

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* y  = a.panGestureRecognizer;  
    y.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    y.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:y];
```

After adding the `panGestureRecognizer` of `a` to `self`, `a` would no longer have the `panGestureRecognizer`.

What should I do such that even after adding the  UIPanGestureRecognizer to `self`, `a` would still have it with itself (such as duplicating it)?

I tried this as suggested by meronix but get exception.

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer* y  = [a.panGestureRecognizer copy]; //I'm using ARC so I didn't add autorelease.
 [self addGestureRecognizer:y];
```

`-[UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5c2460`

Comment: why do you even want to copy it? The proper way to go is to create a new recognizer. If you want more convenience, create a service method that will do the setup for you.

Comment: As per my downvoted answer...

Comment: Have you tried `[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:action:]` with the same action that was used for `a.panGestureRecognizer`

Comment: have you tired this answer  over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913203/uigesturerecognizer-in-uitableview-crash-after-scrolling

Comment: @meronix I didn't down vote the question. Given that the question has been open for 6 days and had multiple questions asked back and received no response from the asker... I have now down voted the question.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do, from a high level? For example, if you are trying to have two views on the same parentView react to a gesture, the solution is not to copy the recognizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you merely want to duplicate that gesture recognizer with its current state, then something like:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *r = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                    action:action];
r.minimumNumberOfTouches = a.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches;
r.maximumNumberOfTouches = a.panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches;
[self addGestureRecognizer:r];
```

If however, you want to make sure that any changes that happen to `r` and `a.panGestureRecognizer`, you can set up a helper class to handle this for you.

For example something like this:

```
@interface GestureHandler: NSObject
// ...
- (void)setNewMinTouches(unsigned int)num;
// Weak references to a and r (for example)
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerFromA;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerR;

@end

@implementation GestureHandler
// ...
- (void)setNewMinTouches(unsigned int)num {
    self.gestureRecognizerFromA.minimumNumberOfTouches = num;
    self.gestureRecognzierR.minimumNumberOfTouches = num;
}
// ... and so on.
@end
```

You'd then have to be careful you only interact with the two gesture recognisers through the `GestureHandler` class (unless you specifically want them out of sync).

As katzenhut points out, you could also use this class to generate gesture recognisers as you need them. The standard `-initWithTarget:action:` is really quite useful by itself though.

---

Incidentally, the reason `[gestureRecogniser copy]` doesn't work is because `UIGestureRecognizer` does not implement `-copy`. Therefore, when the message is sent to the gesture recogniser, NSObject's `-copy` method is called which is designed to throw an exception as it is an override point for subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide to make duplicate the instance of gesture. Just because of the gesture is associated to the view and the selector method.
You always have to make new instance for every view with selector method or you can used same method for more gesture.